# Why couldn't the Tenth Doctor travel through time with Rose happily?

Tags: doctor-who

Why couldn't the Tenth Doctor travel through time with Rose happily?

In *Journey's End*,

> The Doctor leaves Rose in the parallel dimension.

Why did he do this? Why didn't he continue to travel with her?

Comment: You seem to have more than one question in there, can you please separate them into their own posts? Also, at the moment, this question is reading more like a "rant in disguise", which is [off-topic](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask) here. Please clarify to focus on the main issues in your question.

Comment: I've removed the ranty portion and made the question clearer. If you have any issues with this, please tell me.

Comment: Why does this still have downvotes? It seems vastly improved, and a good question as it stands.

Answer (score 6):

### Because she'll die and he won't.

From *[School Reunion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/School_Reunion_(Doctor_Who))*:

> ROSE: But Sarah Jane... you were that close to her once, and now... you never even mention her. Why not?
>
> THE DOCTOR: I don't age. I regenerate. But humans decay. You wither and you die. Imagine watching that happen to someone who you...
>
> *He stops when he realizes what he was about to say.*
>
> ROSE: What, Doctor? The Doctor stares at her intensely, as if willing her to understand.
>
> THE DOCTOR: You can spend the rest of your life with me.
>
> *Rose looks up at him, eyes shining with unshed tears.*
>
> THE DOCTOR (CONT'D): But I can't spend the rest of mine with you. I have to live on. Alone. That's the curse of the Time Lords.

The Doctor knows that he'll likely far outlive Rose, and he can't bare to experience that.

In *Journey's End*, he "gives" her his clone specifically because he'll have the same lifespan as her.

> ROSE: Hold on, this is the parallel universe, right?
>
> DOCTOR: You're back home.
>
> DONNA: And the walls of the world are closing again, now that the Reality 
>   Bomb never happened. It's dimensional retroclosure. See, I really get that stuff now.
>
> ROSE: No, but I spent all that time trying to find you. I'm not going back now.
>
> DOCTOR: But you've got to. Because we saved the universe, but at a cost. And the cost is him. He destroyed the Daleks. He committed genocide. He's too dangerous to be left on his own.
>
> NEW DOCTOR: You made me.
>
> DOCTOR: Exactly. You were born in battle, full of blood and anger and revenge. Remind you of someone? That's me, when we first met. And you made me better. Now you can do the same for him.
>
> ROSE: But he's not you.
>
> DOCTOR: He needs you. That's very me.
>
> DONNA: But it's better than that, though. Don't you see what he's trying to give you? Tell her. Go on.
>
> NEW DOCTOR: I look like him and I think like him. Same memories, same thoughts, same everything. Except I've only got one heart.
>
> ROSE: Which means?
>
> NEW DOCTOR: I'm part human. Specifically, the aging part. I'll grow old and never regenerate. I've only got one life, Rose Tyler. I could spend it with you, if you want.
>
> ROSE: You'll grow old at the same time as me?
>
> NEW DOCTOR: Together.

Comment: Let's not forget the part where The Metacrisis Doctor also is more capable of sharing his emotions with her.  When asked what the last thing The Doctor said to Rose on the beach on the worst day of her life, The Doctor said "Rose Tyler.." and when asked how the sentence was going to end he replied "Does it need saying?"  Then when she asks the other Doctor he whispers to her, one can only speculate that he confessed his feelings to her which in turn caused her to kiss him.

Answer (score 1):

There's a cut out scene from Journey's End wher The Doctor gives the clone Doctor a piece of TARDIS coral, implying that he could "grow" himself a new TARDIS.  So there's an argument that The Doctor Rose ARE travelling the spaceway's of Pete's World.